# Neo4j DynamicRecord Not in use

Tags: neo4j

Started to get inconsistency exceptions from my Neo4j 2.2.3 production database yesterday :(

```
Unhandled exception: Neo4jClient.NeoException: RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.InvalidRecordException: DynamicRecord Not in use
```

Running a backup gives me:

```
2016-11-17 05:35:33.801+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Inconsistencies found: ConsistencySummaryStatistics{
Number of errors: 55
Number of warnings: 0
Number of inconsistent NODE records: 29
Number of inconsistent PROPERTY records: 23
Number of inconsistent RELATIONSHIP records: 2
Number of inconsistent INDEX records: 1
```

}

I used https://github.com/jexp/store-utils successfully 2 years ago to repair another database in another project but now I cannot get it to work. Is there any other way to solve these kind of problems??

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make sure you run on either latest patch release on your . version or to upgrade to a more recent . (latest path).

The store-utils you mentioned is among the better ways of generically salvaging as much data as possible from broken stores. Otherwise specific transactions can be performed to fix the inconsistencies, but that may require some investigation and careful incisions.

Comment: Thanks Mattias! So you mean upgrading can repair an inconsistent store? I know I have to do it sooner or later but I didn't had the time or energy as long as everything worked fine :)